# Creating a Failstate in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
elif schoice2 == 2:
    print "You run away from the bear about as fast as Usian Bolt, even though you have no clue who that is since it's the year 1112, but you decide not to dwell on who or what a 'Usian Bolt' is. The bear gives chase, then ultimitely crashes down on you, giving you a fast death."
    print "YOU ARE DEAD, TRY AGAIN!"
```

So I want to know if there is a command that stops a running script completely.

Comment: `sys.exit(0)`?  Your question is kind of vague ... ...

Comment: [```raise```](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) an Exception.?

Comment: Do you want to use [`raise`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) as wwii said to raise an error? or use [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.exit) as g.d.d.c said to exit the program?

Comment: Just to exit the program if certain parameters are met, such as certain choices a user makes in a game.

Comment: If you just want to exit the program, take a look about [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

Comment: thanks :) Sorry that my question was kinda vague

Comment: Okay, and I think use `raise` to raise an error to user before exit is a good idea(at least print something to tell the user what's wrong). :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exit the script in your code you would have to do this:

The `sys.exit()` function will exit the program, and will give an error message. This is the function performing as wanted.

```
import sys
#do some stuff
elif schoice2 == 2:
    print "You run away from the bear about as fast as Usian Bolt, even though you have no clue who that is since it's the year 1112, but you decide not to dwell on who or what a 'Usian Bolt' is. The bear gives chase, then ultimitely crashes down on you, giving you a fast death."
    print "YOU ARE DEAD, TRY AGAIN!"
    sys.exit()
```

EDIT:

The `quit()` function will not give the error message, and will just end the program.

The new code would look like this:

```
import sys
#do some stuff
elif schoice2 == 2:
    print "You run away from the bear about as fast as Usian Bolt, even though you have no clue who that is since it's the year 1112, but you decide not to dwell on who or what a 'Usian Bolt' is. The bear gives chase, then ultimitely crashes down on you, giving you a fast death."
    print "YOU ARE DEAD, TRY AGAIN!"
    quit()
```